# Find root in dictionary-tree

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, root

I have a dictionary-tree like this:

```
{ b : [e], a : [b,c], c : [], e : []}
```

How can I find the root(in this example 'a`) fast even if I have a very long dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk the adjacency list, put each "from" node into a set of source nodes, and each of its corresponding "to" nodes into a set of destination nodes.

Subtracting the set of destinations from the set of sources will yield one of the following:

- **An empty set** - this means that your adjacency list does not represent a tree or a forest,
- **A set with multiple nodes** - this means that your adjacency list represents a forest, or
- **A set with a single item** - this is the root of the tree represented by your adjacency list.

Here is how this works for your example:

- `source`: `{ b, a, c, e }`
- `destination`: `{ e, b, c }`
- `source \ destination`: `{ a }`

Answer (score 1):

In your example the variables (a, b, c, e) are not defined. Assuming you can replace them by strings (or even integers):

```
d = {'b':['e'], 'a':['b','c'], 'c':[], 'e':[]}

root = set(d).difference(*d.values()).pop()
print(root)

--> a
```